# Laravel - Image does not show up

Tags: php, laravel, image

**syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ')' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ramashoes\resources\views\admin\show.blade.php)**

i got that message

after wrote this code

`<img src="{{asset('img/{{$shoes->brand}}/{{$shoes->gambar}}')}}" class="card-img-top">`

i write this before

`<img src="{{asset('img/{$shoes->brand}/{$shoes->gambar}')}}" class="card-img-top">`

but that result is 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdbYB.png)

Comment: This should be like `<img src="{{asset('img/'.$shoes->brand .'/' .$shoes->gambar .')' }}" class="card-img-top">`.

Comment: Have you tried concatenating?

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
<img src="{{asset('img/{$shoes->brand}/{$shoes->gambar}')}}" class="card-img-top">
```

replace single quote with double quote:

```
<img src="{{asset("img/{$shoes->brand}/{$shoes->gambar}")}}" class="card-img-top">
```

I think you can omit the single curley braces too:

```
<img src="{{asset("img/$shoes->brand/$shoes->gambar")}}" class="card-img-top">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="{{asset('img/'.$shoes->brand.'/'.$shoes->gambar.')}}" class="card-img-top">
```